# Replace comma (,) in string elcosed in double quotes

Tags: csv, vbscript

I am importing a csv file which contains comma as part of the string enclosed in double quotes, like one below:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,"b,c,d,e",f
```

In order to get the correct fields, I want to first alter each line, so I get this desired output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,"b;c;d;e",f
```

I did search first, but I didn't find anything else on Stack Overflow, and I only rarely work in vbscript. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Edited to add the code I used to complete this task

```
Sub csv2tab()
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2

    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Global = True
    regex.Pattern = """[^""]*""|[^,]*"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\venkat\Desktop\Freelancers\Upwork_tasks\Chris Hickey\Datafiles\smallerfile_11.csv", ForReading)

    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine
        strLine = Replace(strLine, regex.Replace(Line, ","), vbTab)
        strNewText = strNewText & strLine & vbCrLf
    Loop
    objFile.Close

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\venkat\Desktop\Freelancers\Upwork_tasks\Chris Hickey\Datafiles\test.txt", ForWriting)

    objFile.WriteLine strNewText
    objFile.Close
End Sub
```

In the above code, I am trying to change the delimiter to tab as well but is not mandatory for me. I think I messed up somewhere with the regular expression.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Make an effort to solve this problem yourself. If you run into difficulties, you can then explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question about that code, and we'll try and help. Good luck.

Comment: Using `Split(input, ",")` to parse csv data makes me sad. This is only one edge case of many. Look for a dedicated, purpose-built csv parser instead of `Split()`, and suddenly this problem goes away.

Comment: @KenWhite, I updated the topic with the code I tried.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I think split works to split the row into columns as with the delimiters not sure if it does work for this purpose.

Comment: Split() _sometimes_ works for this, but it's a very poor way to do it. Csv data can have way more corner cases than you'd think that won't work with Split()

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, Any idea where I messed up in the above code? I think it should work with the regular expression but I may be missing something in the pattern.

Comment: Regex isn't much better than Split(). You really want a good state-machine-based dedicated parser. A quick google search indicates it's common to use Excel Ole to do this. I was surprised not to see something ready-built near the top of the results.

Comment: The code you posted is not VBScript, and your data format doesn't seem to be valid CSV.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I am confident, the format is in csv and this is how I can see the actual data as well. Even I myself put some data into excel with comma separated values into single cell and saved it as csv.

Comment: The number of header fields (6) and the number of data fields (3) in your example don't match.

Answer (score 1):

A **decent** .CSV has the same number of columns in each row (and a column header). So your sample data should be:

```
"C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6"
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,"b1,b2,b3",c,d,"e1,e2,e3,e4",f
```

A **decent** tool for working with .CSV deals with special cases (e.g. separator in quoted fields) automagically:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sDDir : sDDir = goFS.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Dim oCN : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim sCS : sCS = Join(Array( _
     "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)" _
   , "DBQ=" & sDDir _
   , "Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt" _
), ";")
Dim oRS

WScript.Echo "sCS:", sCS
oCN.Open sCS
Set oRS = oCN.Execute("SELECT * FROM [44187292.csv]")
WScript.Echo oRS.GetString(2, , vbCrLf, vbCrLf & "----------" & vbCrLf, "<null>")
oCN.close
```

output:

```
cscript 44187292.vbs
sCS: Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);DBQ=e:\work\proj\soa\tmp;Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt
a
b
c
d
e
f
----------
a
b1,b2,b3
c
d
e1,e2,e3,e4
f
----------
```